# sending single mail using Alibaba Cloud Direct Mail?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am using a REST API call to trigger a mail from my application. The request as follows

```
https://dm.aliyuncs.com/?Action=SingleSendMail
&AccountName=test@example.com
&ReplyToAddress=true
&AddressType=1   
&ToAddress=test1@example.com
&Subject=Subject
&HtmlBody=body
&<Public request parameter>
```

I assume from the example it is a GET Call, How can I upload attachments along with the request?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a GET Call. I assume you are referring to the below link

https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/29444.htm

I don't think you can upload attachments with this REST Interface. One other option would be to create a third-party API which will, in turn, use the SDK's(JAVA/Node) to facilitate the attachments addition.

Answer (score 0):

Email attachments are part of the email body.

Most people use a MIME encoding library to process the body of their emails to include the attachments. This also means that you must use HTML mail.

Note: Since you are using the REST API, I wrote an article on how to use the Alibaba DirectMail REST API with real working code in Python: [DirectMail REST API](https://www.neoprime.io/info/alibaba/devops/day_05.php)

Here is an example of what an email looks like with an attachment:

```
From: John Doe <example@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="XXXXboundary text"

This is a multipart message in MIME format.

--XXXXboundary text 
Content-Type: text/plain

this is the body text

--XXXXboundary text 
Content-Type: text/plain;
Content-Disposition: attachment;
        filename="test.txt"

this is the attachment text

--XXXXboundary text--
```

Here is example Python code for email attachments: [Python Examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Here are the email package modules we'll need
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

COMMASPACE = ', '

# Create the container (outer) email message.
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Our family reunion'
# me == the sender's email address
# family = the list of all recipients' email addresses
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(family)
msg.preamble = 'Our family reunion'

# Assume we know that the image files are all in PNG format
for file in pngfiles:
    # Open the files in binary mode.  Let the MIMEImage class automatically
    # guess the specific image type.
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    msg.attach(img)

# Send the email via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, family, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```